# How many people can register at a given apartment at a time?

Tags: germany

In Germany, once moving into a place of permeant residence, it is required to  register the address with some city council. I would like to ask, is there a cap to number of the of people who can register on a given apartment? What factors does this cap depend upon?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The German term you are looking for is *Überbelegung*. As usual, the details depend on the specific situation, and also on the state. If you are a tenant in this situation, talk e.g. to the local *Mieterverein*.

- In the state of [Berlin](https://gesetze.berlin.de/bsbe/document/jlr-WoAufGBEV5P7), the minimum is 9 square meters per person (only 6 square meters per child below the age of six).
- For a rental property, the landlord may be able to specify the number of tenants, and/or charge a higher rent if there are more tenants.
- It may make a difference if the people in the residence are one family, and especially if the *Überbelegung* was only created by the birth of an additional child.